# Typescript compiler generates unused variable when using enum value as an interface property name

Tags: typescript

The typescript compiler (tsc version 3.2.2) add a `require` statement when using an enum as property name in a interface while it does not when using it as a property value:

Assuming I have an enum defined in a file:

```
// props.ts
export enum  PROPS {
  A = 'PROP_A',
  B = 'PROP_B',
}
```

And, in a second file, an interface that uses the enum to specify the property name:

```
// ifce.ts
import { PROPS } from './props';

export interface ISomething {
  [PROPS.A]: string;
}
```

`tsc ifce.ts` produces a variable `props_1`

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
// ifce.ts
var props_1 = require("./props");
```

On the other hand, if an enum is used as property value:

```
// ifce.ts
import { PROPS } from './props';

export interface ISomething {
  someKey: PROPS;
}
```

The output does not produces any variable:

```
// ifce.js
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
```

Is there a way to prevent the generation of this unused variable in case of a property name, the same way it is with a property value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a compiler bug. Generally imports are elided when they are not used in expressions and are only used in types. This is documented in the [FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-imports-being-elided-in-my-emit).

So for example this code does not emit the code for the import since `PROPS.A` is only use in a type annotation

```
import { PROPS } from './props';

let A : PROPS.A
```

If we use the `PROPS` enum in an expression then  the import will not be elided, so for example this code will produce the code for the import :

```
import { PROPS } from './props';

let  A = PROPS.A
```

Computed properties are a bit of a special construct, since although they are in a type, the computed property name must be an expression (a simple expression of a literal type of a unique symbol type, but an expression nonetheless), and believe this is what is causing (mistakenly in my opinion) the compiler to consider the import as used.

As a workaround, you can use a level of indirection, you can declare a `const` of the enum member type, and use that in the interface declaration.

```
import { PROPS } from './props';

declare const A: PROPS.A
export interface ISomething {
    [A]: string;
}
```

This will prevent the compiler from emitting code for the import as `PROPS.A` is only used in the type annotation for `A` and then that const is used in the interface definition. And since this is only an interface the fact that the const does not exist at runtime does not matter.

**Note** You can use the trick to take in the whole enum :

```
import { PROPS } from './props';

declare const LOCAL_PROPS: typeof PROPS
export declare interface ISomething {
    [LOCAL_PROPS.A]: string;
}
```

**Note** [Created an issue for this.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29263)